# Square Bullet in XSL-FO

Tags: xslt, unicode, formatting, xsl-fo

I am attempting to create a list in XSL-FO using a square bracket. I have been able to get it working using the standard unicode bullet character (`&#8226;`) but I just can't seem to get it working for square brackets.

I have tried using `&#9632;`, but that does not seem to work. It is important that i can get the square bullets working because I am matching an existing file format.Any help in getting this working would be greatly appreciated.

```
         <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
          <fo:block>&#x2022;</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-label>
```

Comment: What is the declared character encoding of your document?  Can you provide a small example of your XSL-FO for us to evaluate?  What XSL-FO engine are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i have tried this with my own XSL-FO code and RenderX XEP 4.x and it appears to be a font glyph issue. When I use a font such as the WGL version of Times New Roman it appears correctly as a square bracket, but when I use the built in Helvetica font it doesn't as it doesn't have a glyph which supports it (• works fine).

If you don't want to go to the expense of purchasing a new font I would suggest using a gif to simulate the square bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Is this character included in the font you are using?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think so. I am using Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif. As far as I can tell I have matched the original font.